# Http request unside a pdf file

Tags: http-post, pdf-generation

I send a pdf file to some customers. I want to know witch are opened my file. My dream will be to have a http request post inside the pdf to my server. But i search on some website without result.

Someone know if it's possible? And how i could do that?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I would consider it bad practise and a security risk if it would be possible. And there may be a lot of ways to view the pdf without executing the javascript (e.g. ghostscript or rather simple pdf viewers)

Comment: While technically possible to insert JS that executes on document open, it would never work. Many viewers don't support it and even if they do , they allow the end user to decide yes or no as to if they allow.it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not sure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the PDF file, you might want to send a link (unique to each recipient) where the PDF can be downloaded. This link can log which of the recipients has downloaded the PDF.

This will be easier to set up and your results will be more trustworthy.